# Bootstrap files not load properly in other codeigniter pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

load view file from index function it there no problem to load bootstrap files.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('page_one');      
}
```

When I try to load the view from other functions, then the bootstrap files does not load properly.

```
public function fun_one()
{
    $this->load->view('page_one');      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using relative URLs for your assets.
I could suggest two ways to resolve this issue:

- Use a HTML `<base>` element to specify the base URL for all relative URLs.
- Use absolute URLs for the assets.

#### Using `<base>` element

You could use the HTML [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element in the `<head>`, and set the `href` attribute by using CodeIgniter `base_url()` function:

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
```

Then all the relative URLs use this `href` attribute as the base URL address.

The potential disadvantage of using `<base>` is that it affects the anchor tags as well.

#### Using absolute URLs

In this approach, you need to add the `base_url()` to each assets' URL address. For instance:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```