# CodeIgniter: Inside a controller-class can't go back to pages in one level higher

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new to web development. I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 framework and WAMP server for testing. 
I have followed the tutorial to create the News section, and added some link on the header.php  to go to Home, About, and News. 
All the links work perfectly on the main page and the News page. But once i go into News view page. All the link are broken.

For example, at the home page, all the link will point to

1. localhost/test/home
2. localhost/test/about
3. localhost/test/news

but once i go into News view page, all the link become

1. localhost/test/news/home
2. localhost/test/news/about
3. localhost/test/news/news

I am not too sure what i did wrong or missed.

Comment: I dont know the program but dont your News link have to look the same as in Home page? makes most sence

Comment: You probably are using relative URLs. You could fix that by using `<base>` element in the `<head>` or CodeIgniter's `base_url()` function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21739689/1725764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a leading / to your links and referencing everything starting from the root of your domain.

Example:

a href='test' gets you www.yoursite.com/(yourdir)/test

a href='/test' always gets you www.yoursite.com/test

Comment: This only works if the website is on the root path of the domain

Comment: if it's not on the root domain, you can still reference everything.  You just may need to use a variable before the files you specify.  ex) /$sitedir/my/location