# css not linking to html file in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, hyperlink

I am new to CI , to test how it works i started by making css file an then a html file, but the problem is that i cannot link my css file to the html one.
This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code/application/style/style.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 Hi
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
body
{
    background-color: black ;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap files not load properly in other codeigniter pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739397/bootstrap-files-not-load-properly-in-other-codeigniter-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images, css files etc need to reside outside the application folder, preferably in an "assets" folder that is located on the same level. You can then link to them in your views like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
```

Your folder structure would be:

```
ci-project
-index.php
-application
-assets
--css // --> style.css
--img // --> logo.png
```

Comment: See my updated answer. It's a matter of properly structuring your CI-install's subfolders.

Comment: It is structured the way you need it to be

Comment: In application/config/config.php your base_url should be set as follows: `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Comment: Also, your html files should reside in `application/views/`, with a `.php`extension.

Comment: I have copied and pasted $config['base_url'] = ''; and checked if my view was in application/views/ with a .php extension , everything is as you want it to be but its sill not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ?:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../code/application/style/style.css">
```